# Pandas: Filter by date range / exact id

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm looking to filter a large dataframe (millions of rows) based on another much smaller dataframe that has only three columns: ID, Start, End.

The following is what I put together (which works), but it seems like a `groupby()` or `np.where` might be faster.

**SETUP:**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

csv = io.StringIO(u'''
time    id  num
2018-01-01 00:00:00 A   1
2018-01-01 01:00:00 A   2
2018-01-01 02:00:00 A   3
2018-01-01 03:00:00 A   4
2018-01-01 04:00:00 A   5
2018-01-01 05:00:00 A   6
2018-01-01 06:00:00 A   6
2018-01-03 07:00:00 B   10
2018-01-03 08:00:00 B   11
2018-01-03 09:00:00 B   12
2018-01-03 10:00:00 B   13
2018-01-03 11:00:00 B   14
2018-01-03 12:00:00 B   15
2018-01-03 13:00:00 B   16
2018-05-29 23:00:00 C   111
2018-05-30 00:00:00 C   122
2018-05-30 01:00:00 C   133
2018-05-30 02:00:00 C   144
2018-05-30 03:00:00 C   155
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep = '\t')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

csv_filter = io.StringIO(u'''
id  start   end
A   2018-01-01 01:00:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00
B   2018-01-03 09:00:00 2018-01-03 12:00:00
C   2018-05-30 00:00:00 2018-05-30 08:00:00
''')

df_filter = pd.read_csv(csv_filter, sep = '\t')
df_filter['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filter['start'])
df_filter['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filter['end'])
```

**WORKING CODE**

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df, df_filter, left_on = 'time', right_on = 'start', by = 'id').dropna(subset = ['start']).drop(['start','end'], axis = 1)
df = pd.merge_asof(df, df_filter, left_on = 'time', right_on = 'end', by = 'id', direction = 'forward').dropna(subset = ['end']).drop(['start','end'], axis = 1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                  time id  num
0  2018-01-01 01:00:00  A    2
1  2018-01-01 02:00:00  A    3
6  2018-01-03 09:00:00  B   12
7  2018-01-03 10:00:00  B   13
8  2018-01-03 11:00:00  B   14
9  2018-01-03 12:00:00  B   15
11 2018-05-30 00:00:00  C  122
12 2018-05-30 01:00:00  C  133
13 2018-05-30 02:00:00  C  144
14 2018-05-30 03:00:00  C  155
```

Any thoughts on a more elegant / faster solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `merge` before filter. notice this will eating up your memory when the data set are way to big .

```
newdf=df.merge(df_filter)
newdf=newdf.loc[newdf.time.between(newdf.start,newdf.end),df.columns.tolist()]
newdf
Out[480]: 
                  time id  num
1  2018-01-01 01:00:00  A    2
2  2018-01-01 02:00:00  A    3
9  2018-01-03 09:00:00  B   12
10 2018-01-03 10:00:00  B   13
11 2018-01-03 11:00:00  B   14
12 2018-01-03 12:00:00  B   15
15 2018-05-30 00:00:00  C  122
16 2018-05-30 01:00:00  C  133
17 2018-05-30 02:00:00  C  144
18 2018-05-30 03:00:00  C  155
```

Comment: What are you merging on?

Comment: @elPastor id , key can search by default (intersection columns)

Comment: As far as I can tell, that does the trick.  I like to be a little more explicit in regards to which keys are being merged, but this is great.  Knew there was a more elegant solution.  Thanks!